# What are the http codes to automatically retry the request?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud-feign, spring-retry

I am using the mix Spring-Cloud + feign + spring-retry to help retry requests on the client side (all are Kotlin-based back-ends)

My spring-boot conf is like this:

```
myApp:
  ribbon:
    OkToRetryOnAllOperations: true
    retryableStatusCodes: 404, 503
```

(note: OkToRetryOnAllOperations=true is only present to retry also POST/PUT requests)

Retrying 404 & 503 HTTP codes sounds good, but I cannot figure out if there is a "classic" or "default" list of error codes to retry.
Does this kind of good practice exist?

We suppose all the requests are idempotent on the server side (if not, retrying could cause problems).

Comment: Those codes could be relevant to retry the requests too:
408, 500, 502, 504 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which HTTP errors should never trigger an automatic retry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680711/which-http-errors-should-never-trigger-an-automatic-retry)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As a very rough rule of thumb:
4XX - client did something bad
5XX - server did something bad

But it very much depends of the actual API.
Should you retry 500? Maybe, because the server had an unexpected hiccup while connecting to DB. Or, maybe you're sending it something it's not expecting, and instead of returning you 4XX it crashes.

There is usually not much reason to retry 404, unless you expect that this resource will appear.

The only HTTP codes which is valid for retry are 408, 502, 503 and 504

AWS clients also retry 429.

Comment: Thank for your response. I thought that 404 was relevant in the case of network problems on the client side, don't you think?

Comment: No, because those are the errors returned by the server. The fact that you got 404 means that you managed to reach the server.

Comment: you're right, if the resource does not exist, there is no chance that a retry makes it appear... thank!

Comment: 429s are also retryable.

Comment: Only retry 429s if you know what to wait for. You're creating undue load and your retries may deplete rate limiting quota continuously.

Answer (score 16):

In general, I recommend these:

- 408 Request Timeout
- 425 Too Early
- 429 Too Many Requests
- 500 Internal Server Error
- 502 Bad Gateway
- 503 Service Unavailable
- 504 Gateway Timeout

But it really depends on the API, so you can look up its documentation if it has it. For example, Whatsapp uses 500 for errors that can be retried or not.

Comment: But should 418 be retried?

Comment: not, but you should have your cup ready

Comment: Yay for the answer.  Boo to whatsapp for making everything 500.