# What HTTP error codes are retried by Polly (.Net) by default?

Tags: .net, polly

I know I can specify the list of HTTP error codes (e.g. 408, 502, 503, etc. ) I would like to get retried using [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly), but what is the list of these codes that would be retried by default if none is specified?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What is the list of [Http status] codes that would be retried by default [by Polly] if none is specified?

Polly on its own contains no built-in definitions of what it retries, you as the user [specify that when defining a policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#step-1--specify-the--exceptionsfaults-you-want-the-policy-to-handle).

Polly with HttpClientFactory (using `services.AddHttpClient(...).AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(...)` in `StartUp` in .Net Core) retries the following items, per the [Polly with HttpClientFactory documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#using-addtransienthttperrorpolicy):

- Network failures (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException)
- HTTP 5XX status codes (server errors)
- HTTP 408 status code (request timeout)

This [should also be shown in the intellisense](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/c38f9c1e04a380870f4ae5b16bbcd7e2e49854b4/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/DependencyInjection/PollyHttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L203-L205) when you hover over the method.

The `HandleTransientHttpError()` method available via the [`Polly.Extensions.Http`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly.Extensions.Http) package also [handles the same set of exceptions and status codes](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#extending-the-convenience-addtransienthttperrorpolicy-definition).

Comment: It seems that polly throws only about timedoutexceptions. Not about the other error codes

Comment: Can you please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835490/polly-wont-throw-on-some-exceptions)  ?

Comment: to retry all 5xx errors is too broad  list(e.g. 501 NotImplemented doesn’t make sense to retry).
Consider 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770071/what-are-the-http-codes-to-automatically-retry-the-request/74627395#74627395 list instead and retryHttpStatusCodesList   implementation from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019007/how-to-set-polly-retry-for-the-set-specific-statuscodes-only question