# How do I perform retry based on HTTP response code in Springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-retry, resilience4j-retry

```
@Retryable(value = ABCDException.class,
        maxAttemptsExpression = 3,
        backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{${application.delay}}"))

public String postABCDrequest(ABCDrequest abcdRequest) throws ABCDException {
    try {
        return restCalltopostData(abcdRequest);
    } catch (AnyException e) {
        log.error("Error Occured ", e);
        throw new ABCDException("Error Occured ", e);
    }
}
```

In this method, I need to retry posting data only when I get certain response codes. I have searched for a few options which isnt suitable for my solution. Is there any simpler way by using annotation?

Comment: Can you please provide the response codes where you prefer to retry?

Comment: for example if the response code is > 500 , I would want to retry.. 
Here, catch block has AnyException. I wouldn't want all cases to be retried. Only specific cases to be retried. I can seperate them with response codes and hoping to retry with that

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680711/which-http-errors-should-never-trigger-an-automatic-retry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In catch block, you won't be able to get hold of the response code. Since you're interested in all `5xx`, put a check for `response.getStatusCode().is5xxServerError()` and re-throw the exception `ABCDException.class` if the exceptions are well handled at the server end and returns the status code. This way you code will continue to retry for all `5xx` exceptions until the `maxAttempts` gets exhausted.

Else, you can simply retry for `HttpServerErrorException.class` by replacing `ABCDException.class`.